# select single property in hstore field with Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I am using Postgres 9.3 with Rails 4.1.

Suppose I have a table with a `properties` hstore colum.

I now want to select a single key inside the hstore column in a scope (or somewhere else..)

What I tried:
`Model.select("properties -> 'category'")`

What happens: Rails gives me an array like this:

```
[#<Model id: nil>,
 #<Model id: nil>,
 #<Model id: nil>,
 #<Model id: nil>]
```

What I want:

```
[#<Model id: nil, category: 'foo'>,
 #<Model id: nil, category: 'bar'>,
 #<Model id: nil, category: 'baz'>,
 #<Model id: nil, category: 'foo'>]
```

Comment: Does `Model.where("properties ? 'category'")` work?

Comment: This doesn't accomplish the thing I want to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=>  Model.where("properties @> hstore(?, ?)", 'key', 'value').select(:category)
=> [#<Model id: nil, category: 'foo'>]
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, an explanation of what the code does and why this is the best solution for the OP would greatly improve this answer, and help future visitors.